# How to make backward compatibility of framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-c++, dll, clr

Normally I find an answer on the internet or try to find my own solution to the problem, but this time, after searching and fighting with it over a day, I give up. Maybe you can help me out.

So I know little bit around in C++.
I am a PLC programmer and I am using a HMI program that uses framework 3.5. Now I would like to make a custom control library for that program, but I have a big problem to build it as framework 3.5.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, framework 4.5, and I have installed framework 3.5 also (it is default installed with Windows 7 Professional).
All of these following steps I managed to find on internet.

Here is what i did:
I am making a new CLR Class Library with Framework 3.5 chosen.

And then afterwards I check which version of framework is actually set in project file, and I can see this:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

So the framework version is OK.

I add a new item as UI -> CLR User Control, and on form I put just a couple of labels to see if it is going to build a solution and make the dll file.
The build is of course successful.

Afterwards I check version of framework in dll file with dotPeek and it says it is framework 4.0.

Some more information from dotPeek:

References:

```
   mscorlib (2.0.0.0)
   mscorlib (4.0.0.0)
   System (2.0.0.0)
   System (4.0.0.0)
   System.Data (2.0.0.0)
   System.Drawing (2.0.0.0)
   System.Windows.Forms (2.0.0.0)
   System.Xml (2.0.0.0)
```

It is clear that there are 2 libraries that are version 4.0.

So my question is, why won't it build as 3.5, because I defined it as 3.5 in VS2013.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You must have VS2008 SP1 installed to do this.  Details [are here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/11/22/framework-multi-targeting-for-vc-projects.aspx).